# Keeping named_scope Extensions DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope

In Rails, you can add a block after a `named_scope` for additional, context-sensitive methods like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :inactive, :conditions => {:active => false} do
    def activate
      each { |i| i.update_attribute(:active, true) }
    end
  end
end
```

In this example, the `activate` method is being defined not on the `User` class, but on the `ActiveRecord::NamedScope::Scope` object.

I have a series of three scopes that need to have identical method definitions. In the interests of not repeating code, how would I abstract that block such that I could define it once and pass it to each `named_scope`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, great question--I didn't know about that feature of named scopes! The following works for me:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  add_activate = lambda do
    define_method "activate" do
      each { |i| i.update_attribute(:active, true) }
    end
  end

  named_scope :inactive, :conditions => {:active => false}, &add_activate
end
```

You can pass the `add_activate` block as the last argument to any named scopes that need the `activate` method.

Comment: Thanks! I was forgetting the `&`. Knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Much better:

http://tuxicity.se/rails/dry/2009/01/04/share-named-scopes-in-rails.html

```
module NamedScope
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      named_scope :inactive, :conditions => {:active => false} do
        def activate
          each { |i| i.update_attribute(:active, true) }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Save in your `/lib` directory (put a require in an initializers in rails 3) and `include NamedScope` in your `User` class